# Stop Tomcat from copying exploded war directory

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

Following the [docs here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html), I deploy a web app from a directory:

```
curl -u user:pass \
 'http://www.example.com:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/myapp&war=/path/to/myapp'
```

This copies `/path/to/myapp` to the host's `appBase`. Is there a way to stop that? Can't tomcat use the exploded war directory given in the parameter without copying it?

**Update:**

A comment asked why I don't put a link in the `appBase`.

If I put the exploded war under the host's `appBase`, or if I put a symlink there, pointing to the exploded war outside of `appBase`, then if I try to deploy:

```
curl -u user:pass 'http://www.example.com:8080/manager/text/deploy?war=myapp'
```

The following error appears in `catalina.out`:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.copy 
 Error copying [myapp] to [/Users/rob/Dev/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/my_apps/myapp]
```

Tomcat 9.0.20

Comment: why don;t you just create a simlink from your app folder to /webapps/ ?

Comment: I updated the question to explain why. I tried that first and was getting an error. (I tried the directory first, but after your comment I tried with a sym link too, and I get the same error.)

Comment: Why do you care where it deploys it?  What if it doesn't have permission to explode the `.war` file?

Comment: There is no war file; I’m creating and deploying a directory tree. This is my local dev environment. I care because I want to minimize the work and time it takes to reload new code. Second, I think docs should be accurate. The docs say this works, so if it doesn’t they should be fixed.